# Missing Dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg, gdebi

I'm trying to install Lightworks on my Ubuntu 19.10 desktop but when installing it, gdebi stops because it's missing the dependency 'libssl1.0.0'. Any advice will be helpful.

The link to the screenshot is the underlined sentence below.

[image: The error message when using gdebi.]

Comment: There is no `libssl1.0.0` in `eoan repos.

Comment: You don't need to use gdebi in 19.10. Simply tell apt the path to the deb file: $ sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb.

Comment: It won't install alnyway on 19.10.

Comment: So this deb won't install on 19.10.

Comment: I would recommend to try [latest beta](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_lwks&view=download&Itemid=206) instead.

Comment: I looked at dependencies. `libssl1.0.0` may be installable on 19.10, but that's not recommended.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This deb file is incompatible with Ubuntu 19.10 release, because it requires `libssl1.0.0` package that is unavailable.

You can install it on Ubuntu 18.04, or look for a newer `lightworks` release.

You can find a beta at the same place.